# Password protected post or page - error message by wrong password?

Tags: pages, password

Ok guys, I'm building a page, where a certain sub-page is password protected. Easy in wordpress. But there is a UX problem: when a user enters a wrong password, theres no error message or something to indicate, that the password is not correct.

Is it posible to manually code it somehow to the template file?

Comment: Show your code...then only we able to give answers

Answer (score 5):

not really, but can try something like:

```
add_action('wp', 'check_post_pass');

function check_post_pass(){

  if(!is_single() || !post_password_required()) return;

  global $post;
  if(isset($_COOKIE['wp-postpass_'.COOKIEHASH])
      && $_COOKIE['wp-postpass_'.COOKIEHASH] !== $post->post_password){

    define('INVALID_POST_PASS', true);

    // tell the browser to remove the cookie so the message doesn't show up every time
    setcookie('wp-postpass_'.COOKIEHASH, NULL, -1, COOKIEPATH);
  }

}
```

in your template:

```
if(defined('INVALID_POST_PASS')) _e('The password you entered is funky');
```

But a much better idea would be to create your own `the_content()`-like function and password form + check function, without cookies...

Comment: Just noting that as of [WP v3.4](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.4) passwords are hashed in cookies